# Am I wrong or the horizon-integration-xp1-assets:3.0.0-ltsc2022 is missing the module/db folder?

Tags: sql-database, container, kubernetes

It looks that horizon-integration-xp1-assets:3.0.0-ltsc2022 is missing the module/db folder. Attached is LTSC2022 vs. 1809 Databases Deployment:

**LTSC2022:**

> Step 8/13 : FROM ${HRZ_INTEGRATION_ASSETS_IMAGE} AS hrz_int_assets
> 3.0.0-ltsc2022: Pulling from sxp/modules/horizon-integration-xp1-assets
> Status: Downloaded newer image for scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/horizon-integration-xp1-assets:3.0.0-ltsc2022

> Step 9/13 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
> 10.2-ltsc2022: Pulling from sxp/sitecore-xp1-mssql-init
> Status: Downloaded newer image for scr.sitecore.com/sxp/sitecore-xp1-mssql-init:10.2-ltsc2022

> Step 10/13 : COPY --from=hrz_int_assets C:\module\db C:\resources\hrz
> COPY failed: stat C:\module\db: file does not exist
> ERROR: Service 'mssql-init' failed to build : Build failed

**1809:**

> Step 8/13 : FROM ${HRZ_INTEGRATION_ASSETS_IMAGE} AS hrz_int_assets
> 2.26-1809.: Pulling from sxp/modules/horizon-integration-xp1-assets
> Status: Downloaded newer image for scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/horizon-integration-xp1-assets:2.26-1809.

> Step 9/13 : FROM ${PARENT_IMAGE}
> 10.2-ltsc2022: Pulling from sxp/sitecore-xp1-mssql-init
> Status: Downloaded newer image for scr.sitecore.com/sxp/sitecore-xp1-mssql-init:10.2-ltsc2022

> Step 10/13 : COPY --from=hrz_int_assets C:\module\db C:\resources\hrz
> ---> 4a5015d8362c
> Successfully built af6e5f7aac6e
> Successfully tagged scnext-xp1-mssql-init:latest

Answer (score 1):

Could the issue be related to the fact that Sitecore 10.1+ now supports `Items As Resources` or IAR? There may no longer need to be a folder for database files when the items are stored in `.dat` files.

Comment: Hi, Michael, thanks for the quick reply but I have hit this on Sitecore 10.2 while changing the Kubernetes PODs from ltsc2019 to ltsc2022. It looks that  the containers for ltsc2022 are missing the C:\module\db folder for some reason.

Comment: Might be worth opening a support ticket to see the reason.